How can I make the layout of images match other screen resolutions?
How can I make the layout of images in a program on other computers with a different resolution  be the same as on my computer. For example: I run a program on my computer and everything is fine with the images, but as soon as I run it on another computer, the image layout is not the same as on mine, that is, it does not fit in the screen and extends beyond the screen. How can I make the images on other computers be the same as on mine?
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def open_second_window():
    second_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    second_window.title("window")
    second_window.state('zoomed')


    image_path = "1.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = tk.Label(second_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo 
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0)

    button = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="ONE", command=lambda: open_four_window(second_window))

    button.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.3, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', wraplength=289, text="TWO", command=open_five_window)
    button1.place(relx=0.48, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.3, anchor='ne')
    button = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="THREE", command=open_threee_window)
    button.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.48, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.3, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="FOUR", command=open_threetenfive_window)
    button1.place(relx=0.48, rely=0.48, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.3, anchor='ne')


    tk.Label(second_window, font='Times 30', text="TEXT:", fg="red").place(relx=0.07, rely=0.05)


    third_window.grab_set()
def open_four_window(second_window):
    second_window.destroy()

    four_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    four_window.title("win")
    four_window.state('zoomed')

    image_path = "2.png"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = tk.Label(four_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo  
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(relx=0, rely=0)


    button = tk.Button(four_window,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="START", command=lambda: open_second_window())
    button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(four_window,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="EXIT", command=Close)
    button1.place(relx=1.0, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.50, relheight=0.1, anchor='ne')

    third_window.grab_set()

...
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("menu")
root.state('zoomed')


image_path = "40.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image.thumbnail((1, 1))

label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
label.place(relx=0, rely=0)

def Close(): 
    root.destroy() 

button = tk.Button(root, font='Times 31', text="START", command=lambda: open_second_window())
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, anchor='ne')
button1 = tk.Button(root, font='Times 31', text="EXIT", command=Close)
button1.place(relx=1.0, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.50, relheight=0.1, anchor='ne')


tk.Label(root, font='Times 30', text="red", fg="red text").place(relx=0.1, rely=0.05)
tk.Label(root, font='Times 30 italic', text="descriptions").place(relx=0.35, rely=0.11)

root.mainloop()

p.s. the answer in my previous question didn't help completely, the interface opens fine, but except for the image

It functioned properly. However, you still have numerous errors up to this point.

line 28, in open_second_window
button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="FOUR", command=open_threetenfive_window)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'open_threetenfive_window' is not defined

That's the final one that will function.

You are already using relative positioning (relx, rely) in parts of your code, but not uniformly. To make your layout flexible and adaptable to different screen sizes, ensure that all widgets, including images and buttons, are placed and sized using relative units where possible.
I've rewritten your code with the addition of dynamic layout.
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def resize_image(event, label, image_path):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image=photo)
    label.image = photo

def open_second_window():
    second_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    second_window.title("window")
    second_window.state('zoomed')

    image_path = "1.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = tk.Label(second_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo  # Keep reference to avoid garbage collection
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # Bind the window resize event to dynamically resize the image
    second_window.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: resize_image(event, label, image_path))

    button = tk.Button(second_window, height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="ONE")
    button.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.3, anchor='ne')

    button1 = tk.Button(second_window, height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="TWO")
    button1.place(relx=0.48, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.3, anchor='ne')

...
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("menu")
root.state('zoomed')

image_path = "40.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.image = photo  # Keep reference to avoid garbage collection
label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Bind the window resize event to dynamically resize the image
root.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: resize_image(event, label, image_path))

button = tk.Button(root, font='Times 31', text="START", command=lambda: open_second_window())
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, anchor='ne')

button1 = tk.Button(root, font='Times 31', text="EXIT", command=root.quit)
button1.place(relx=1.0, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, anchor='ne')

root.mainloop()

